# PHP, Facebook like button user verification

Tags: php, javascript, html, facebook

Is there a way to check weather a user actually clicked the like button of my website or not?

I want to give a credit to the user who clicks like button.

If it is not possible to get facebook user IDs of the fan page, I can only think that just storing a data when they click the like button script.

Comment: Not sure, but I don't think you can get the FB UID like that. You probably need to build an app and integrate it in your Facebook Page then you will have access to user data after he likes the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only know whether user has liked your fan page or not, by using a facebook app in fan page.

But, you cannot get an FB id on a website by this approach.

But yes, you can know when user has liked the page.
If you are using your own login system and someone likes your webpage. You can actually save that user's value in database.

Subscribe to like button. Whenever a user clicks on like button, it will call a javascript function. You can call a server side page via ajax call from that function , that server side page can update current user as liker of webpage.

**Refer this on how to subscribe like button:**

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/